# C++ Last object of my vector is overwriting every object

Tags: c++, vector

Here I am trying to create a vector of 5 SavingsAccount objects. Each SavingsAccount has a balance, which the user inputs. My problem is that when I print out the balance, the value of each balance equals whatever was entered last. For example, user inputs 100, 200, 300, etc, my program outputs all 500s instead of each entered balance.

I know there's probably a really simple explanation for this, but I seem to be running out of gas today. My guess is that when I call accounts.push_back, I'm assigning the same object to each element of the vector so that on the last run of the for loop, I'm assigning 5 objects with a balance of 500 into the vector.

If that's the case, I'm not entirely sure how to fix that. Any suggestions, or do I have another problem somewhere?  Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include "SavingsAccount.h" // SavingsAccount class definition
using namespace std;

void initializeAccounts(vector<SavingsAccount> &, int);

int main()
{
    //Number of accounts
    const int NUM_OF_ACCOUNTS = 5;
    //Create vector
    vector <SavingsAccount> accounts(NUM_OF_ACCOUNTS);

    //Initialize all 5 vectors with input from user
    initializeAccounts(accounts, NUM_OF_ACCOUNTS);

    //Print out the balances
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_ACCOUNTS; i++)
    {
        accounts[i].printBalance();
    }

void initializeAccounts(vector<SavingsAccount> &accounts, int accountSize)
{
    double balance = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < accountSize; i++)
    {
        cout << "Please enter the balance for account " << i+1 << endl;
        cin >> balance;

        accounts.push_back(SavingsAccount(balance));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you already set the size of your vector with `NUM_OF_ACCOUNTS` elements:

```
vector <SavingsAccount> accounts(NUM_OF_ACCOUNTS);
```

So when you later `push_back` further elements in your `initialize` method, it adds to the already existing (empty elements)

BTW you pass the size of the vector whereas it is self-contained. But that's another story.

Simple fix: declare vector as empty at the start:

```
vector <SavingsAccount> accounts;
```

Comment: I tried this but got the same result.  Would my problem be inside my class file then?

Comment: Nevermind, it was in my class file. The balance was accidentally a static member. Thank you for your help anyways, I learned something from it!

Answer (score 0):

`vector <SavingsAccount> accounts(NUM_OF_ACCOUNTS);` default constructs `NUM_OF_ACCOUNTS`. Then you push back some more, so you end up with `2 * NUM_OF_ACCOUNTS` items in your vector.

You then iterate over the first constructed elements. Which are of course not the ones you pushed back.

If you want to reserve memory, do this instead:

```
vector <SavingsAccount> accounts;
accounts.reserve(NUM_OF_ACCOUNTS);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches.

Either yoy define an empty vector and the function `initializeAccounts` appends new elements to the vector like

```
accounts.push_back(SavingsAccount(balance));
```

For example

```
vector <SavingsAccount> accounts;

//Initialize all 5 vectors with input from user
initializeAccounts(accounts, NUM_OF_ACCOUNTS);
```

or

```
vector <SavingsAccount> accounts;
accounts.reserve( NUM_OF_ACCOUNTS );

//Initialize all 5 vectors with input from user
initializeAccounts(accounts, NUM_OF_ACCOUNTS);
```

Or you define a vector with a given number as for example

```
vector <SavingsAccount> accounts( NUM_OF_ACCOUNTS );

//Initialize all 5 vectors with input from user
initializeAccounts(accounts, NUM_OF_ACCOUNTS);
```

and inside the function you use

```
accounts[I].balance = balance;
```